# calculate earnings with numbers in lists within dictionary, python3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
stock_listings = {
            'GOOGL': [125, 772.88, 941.53],
            'MSFT' : [85, 56.60, 73.04],
             }
```

this dictionary is formatted as
'stock_name': [shares, purchase_price, current_price]

I need to calculate earning from using numbers inside the dictionary and print out earnings..

earnings = shares * (current_price - purchase_price)

how would you calculate and print out the earnings?

your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Someone will answer your question, but you have to do bit of leg work yourself - First take a look at what a dictionary is in python and how to loop through with keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each stock in the stock_listings dictionary. An easy `print()` solution would be like:

```
for each_stock in stock_listings.keys(): # iterates over each stock symbol in the stock_listings
  curr_stock_data = stock_listings[each_stock] # gets the current stock data from the listings
  curr_stock_earnings = (curr_stock_data[2]-curr_stock_data[1]) * curr_stock_data[0] # calculates this stock earnings with your formula
  print("The stock:", each_stock, ", earned: ", curr_stock_earnings) # outputs your result
```

This will provide an output like:

```
The stock: MSFT , earned:  1397.4000000000003
The stock: GOOGL , earned:  21081.249999999996
```

Comment: @JoonLee You're welcome! If this helped you, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Comment: I just did. Thanks!!

Comment: @ sccoding  one additional question, how would you calculate the earnings using functions and print out the same thing? I am really struggling.. any help is appreciated!!

Comment: @JoonLee That really depends. You can put this entire code and run it as a function by itself, if you're looking to run it multiple times. Does that answer your question? Please elaborate on your question a little more.

Comment: @ sccoding. I am sorry for the confusion. you're so right. I am having hard time putting this entire code and run it as a function and run multiple lines even if I add new line of list and new values in the list... although I can read and understand and see how you did this one but I just can't grab the logic on how I can put this into a function to print out the same thing.. any help is appreciated. I am so new and write something everyday but feel like I have long way to go. Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Comment: @JoonLee I think you're trying to put it into a function to make it reusable. An easy way to do this, would be to make a function:
`def calculate_stock_earnings(stock_listings):`
And then the previous code in my answer. This could be used for multiple values of `stock_listings` if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop

```
for stock in stock_listings:
    shares = stock_listings[stock][0]
```

and so on